# Is it possible to communicate between two different Outlook Add-ins using CustomProperties?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

It's not quite clear from this "The CustomProperties object represents custom properties that are specific to a particular item and specific to a mail add-in for Outlook", from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-preview; if it is not possible, is there perhaps an alternative method? To clarify: I'd like to be able to communicate - a message - from one Outlook Add-in to another, both running in the same Email Client and the same session.

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. I'd suggest posting a feature request on Tech Community. They are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thanks for suggestion; for our use case I've decided to use our SQL Server DB as the communications medium, which will work, but is only a runner as we already have the infrastructure to do that, otherwise it would be an excessively complex solution for a comparatively simple requirement